# Genesis 25:27-34 , was Esau like a famished/hungry whining adolescent/teenager Or was he really Starving, and genuinely needed food?

Tags: genesis, jacob, covenant, esau

> Genesis 25:27-34
> 27 When the boys grew up, Esau became a skillful
> hunter, a man of the field, but Jacob was a [s]peaceful man, [t]living
> in tents. 28 Now Isaac loved Esau, because [u]he had a taste for game,
> but Rebekah loved Jacob. 29 When Jacob had cooked stew, Esau came in
> from the field and **he was [v]famished;** 30 and Esau said to Jacob,
> “Please let me have a swallow of [w]that red stuff there, for **I am
> [x]famished.**” Therefore his name was called [y]Edom. 31 But Jacob
> said, “[z]First sell me your birthright.” 32 Esau said, **“Behold, I
> am about to die; so of what use then is the birthright to me?”** 33
> And Jacob said, “[aa]First swear to me”; so he swore to him, and sold
> his birthright to Jacob. 34 Then Jacob gave Esau bread and lentil
> stew; and he ate and drank, and rose and went on his way. Thus Esau
> despised his birthright.

When reading over Genesis 25:27-34 , was Esau  merely behaving like a whining adolescent/teenager at the kitchen dinner table who complained that he was extremely hungry, and would even give up his birthright for food?
Or
Was Esau the fact that he was famished indicative that he may actually have been in dire straits?  In other words, Esau may have been so hungry, and could Not afford food, etc?

Comment: If someone downvotes then he/she should at least give a reason!!!

Comment: Do said adolescents usually spend their entire day in the woods, hunting for game, as Esau did, or are otherwise involved in other physically-demanding activities ?

Comment: @Lucian , it is interesting to note that in this world, there are many adults, who regardless of whether they are senior citizens or in their Middle ages, still behave like immature kids or adolescents/teenagers.   Therefore, it would be reasonable to think that about Esau

Answer (score 1):

> Genesis 25:29 Once when Jacob was cooking some stew, Esau came in from the open country, famished. 30He said to Jacob, “**Quick**, let me have some of that red stew! I’m famished!”

Esau was impatient and wanted things immediately: I'm so hungry I could eat a horse. He let his appetite rule his brain.

> 31 Jacob replied, “First sell me your birthright.”
>
> 32“Look, I am about to die,” Esau said. “**What good** is the birthright to me?”

Esau continued with more exaggerations about his hunger. But it is telling: He didn't care about the birthright.
Unlike today, being the firstborn was no trivial matter at that time. The technical term is primogeniture. It allows the firstborn to inherit a larger share of his parents' estate. The firstborn theme runs through the entire Bible from Genesis to Revelation.

> Malachi 1:3
> but Esau I have **hated**, and I have turned his hill country into a wasteland and left his **inheritance** to the desert jackals."

Because Esau despised his birthright, his descendants ended up with nothing.

Jacob became Israel. We Christians inherited Judaism.

What Esau did was the dumbest things in the world and in the world history and for what: a dish of red stew that matches his name. He was what he ate.